# A homeomorphism from a countably compact space to a first countable space T 2

Tags: general-topology, compactness

The problem says

Let $X$ be a countably compact space, and $Y$ a first countable T2 -space.
Show that a continuous bijection $f : X → Y$ is a homeomorphism.

I do not know what homomorphism to give?
some clue

Comment: Your question is unclear; use your English to explain what you are trying to ask! I'm guessing, but I think you believe you are asked to find $f$, but the problem is about doing something when $f$ is given to you.

Comment: IF such a function exists. The reason you cannot tell which homeomorphism to give  is that it might not exist. E.g. if $X=\mathbb R^2$ and $Y=\mathbb R.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It suffices to show that $f$ is a closed map. Let $A$ be a closed subset $X$. Then $A$ is countably compact, so $f(A)$ is countably compact too. Therefore it is a closed subset of a first countable $T_2$ space $Y$. Indeed, assume the converse, there exists a point $y\in\overline{f(A)}\setminus f(A)$. Let $U_n$ be a countable base at the point $y$
such that $U_{n+1}\subset U_n$ for each $n$. For each $n$ pick a point $y_n\in U_n\cap f(A)$. The latter condition implies that the sequence $\{y_n\}$ converges to the point $y$. On the other hand, the set $f(A)$ is countably compact, so the set $\{y_n\}$ has a cluster point $y’\in f(A)$. But since the space $Y$ is $T_2$ and the sequence $\{y_n\}$ converges to the point $y$, we should have $y’=y$. But $y’\ne y$ because $y’\in f(A)$, whereas $y\not\in f(A)$, a contradiction.

Comment: $f$ is closed because in a first countable Hausdorff space, sequentially closed implies closed. And a countably compact subset is sequentially closed in a Hausdorff space, and $f$ preserves countable compactness.